# Generalized Conditional Probability proof.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i) > 0$ for any $n>1$. Prove that
$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}A_i)=P(A_1)\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(A_{i+1} |\bigcap_{k=1}^{i}A_k)$$

My attempt:

I tried to prove this by induction. So I first showed that it is true for $n=2$.
$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{2}A_i)=P(A_1)\prod_{i=1}^{1} P(A_{i+1} |\bigcap_{k=1}^{i}A_k)$$
$$P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_{2} |A_1)$$

By definition of conditional probability, this is true. I will now assume this is true for all $n = j$. Now I wish to solve this for $n = j + 1$

$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{j+1}A_i)=P(A_1)\prod_{i=1}^{j} P(A_{i+1} |\bigcap_{k=1}^{i}A_k)$$

I am unsure on how to proceed for here. My uncertainty lies in what end goal I can reach to prove it is true for all $n$. This notation is also intimidating and I do not know what sort of manipulation I can do, considering most if it is intersections and not unions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close with your induction. Let $B := \bigcap_{i=1}^j A_i$ so that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{j+1} A_i = B \cap A_{j+1}$.

Then note $P(B \cap A_{j+1}) = P(A_{j+1} \mid B) P(B)$ and use the induction hypothesis to handle $P(B)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I feel like I'm almost there but I still have a gap in understanding. So since $B := \bigcap_{i=1}^j A_i$, we have $P(B) = P(\bigcap_{i=1}^j A_i) = P(A_1)\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} P(A_{i+1} |\bigcap_{k=1}^{i}A_k)$  Due to the induction hypothesis. Then that means

$P(B \cap A_{j+1}) = P(A_{j+1} \mid B) P(B) = P(A_{j+1} \mid \bigcap_{i=1}^j A_i)P(A_1)\prod_{i=1}^{j-1} P(A_{i+1} |\bigcap_{k=1}^{i}A_k)$

Is this it? I don't feel convinced for some reason.

Comment: Actually I worked through the equation again and it makes perfect sense to me. Awesome, thanks so much.